# How to Bind the data from SQLite in MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

May I ask about how to bind the data dynamically,The Data is from SQLite.
I'm new to MVVM

[image: How to retrieve the data in SQLite]

The Sample [source code](https://github.com/mejiandres-mill/CardStackTest) . The Binding is in MainPageViewModel.cs

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use NuGet to add the Fody.PropertyChanged package to your project and then add the '[ImplementPropertyChanged]' attribute to your data entities.

There are other ways to do this that don't involve polluting your data layer with an attribute but if you're new to MVVM then I'd recommend doing it like this for now.

Comment: No need for this. He can use an ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: An ObservableCollection will only trigger change notifications on the list itself, not the individual properties of the items within that list which is what you usually also need. I guess I depends on his specific needs.

Comment: true, but then again you do not always want to implement inotifyproperychanged for each property. Which Fody does. I think OP wants to bind his data from SQL. Meaning the list.

Comment: I would not recommend fody for a newbie. He would not understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ObservableCollection instead of List for your items. ObservableCollection fires off events when the data changes which will work out for binding.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/